# Cuando hacer peticiones al servidor

Tags: android, webservice, android-fragment, retrofit

tengo un problema, que considero facil, pero debido a mi poca experiencia en Android no logro resolver.

veran, estoy desarrollando una app que obtiene los datos desde un servidor, es decir, hago peticiones para obtener los datos a mostrar Ejm: lista de productos.

tengo una actividad principal, la cual llama a fragmentos por un viewpager, todo funciona bien hasta que deseo entrar a ver un producto, es decir, cuando hago tap sobre uno y me envia a la otra actividad y nuevamente regreso a la actividad principal, parece ser que se duplica el contenido o se vuelve a hacer la peticion y agrega nuevamente los mismos elementos

Este es el codigo del MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager pager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_pager);
        tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        setupViewPager();


    }

private void setupViewPager() {
            pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), buildFragments()));
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_posts);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_message);

        }

        private ArrayList<Fragment> buildFragments() {
            ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

            fragments.add(new PostsFragment());
            fragments.add(new MensajesFragment());

            return fragments;
        }
}
```

las peticiones se hacen en el fragment, primero hacia las peticiones en el estado onResume() pero lo cambie al estado onStart() y sigo teniedo el mismo problema.

Este es el codigo del Fragment

```
public class PostsFragment extends Fragment  {
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private PostsAdapter adapter;

    public static PostsFragment newInstance() {
        PostsFragment fragment = new PostsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public PostsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new PostsAdapter(getActivity());
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_posts, container, false);

        // Obtener el Recycler
        recycler = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.posts_recycler);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        return root;


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Call<PostsResponse> c = ApiAdapter.getApiService().getPosts(ApiCons.API_KEY,"","DESC");
        c.enqueue(new Callback<PostsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostsResponse> call, Response<PostsResponse> response) {
                adapter.agregarTodo(response.body().getPosts());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }
```

podrian ayudarme con su experiencia a solucionar este problema. Gracias.

Comment: sería más sencillo ayudarte si anexas tu código

Comment: @L.Ronquillo ya actualice la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El método onStart, es llamado tanto cuando se crea una actividad, como si se recupera del stack (cuando no se cierra y se regresa a ella), la solución es tan simple como mover todo el código de onStart a onCreate:

```
public class PostsFragment extends Fragment  {
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private PostsAdapter adapter;

    public static PostsFragment newInstance() {
        PostsFragment fragment = new PostsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public PostsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new PostsAdapter(getActivity());
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_posts, container, false);

    // Obtener el Recycler
    recycler = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.posts_recycler);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    recycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    Call<PostsResponse> c = ApiAdapter.getApiService().getPosts(ApiCons.API_KEY,"","DESC");
        c.enqueue(new Callback<PostsResponse>() {
        @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostsResponse> call, Response<PostsResponse> response) {
                adapter.agregarTodo(response.body().getPosts());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });

    return root;


}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}
}
```

Comment: Esto no hace que se vuelva más lento el mostrar la actividad?

Comment: No, y seguramente tu función `Call<PostsResponse>` sea asycronica por lo que no va a ralentizarse para nada. Puedes hacer la prueba tu mismo, no obstante, también pues solucionarlo limpiando la lista antes de agregar los resultados, `tuLista.clear();`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias.